# Using *args, **kwargs to manage API of diverse objects called in a client class (object-oriented design)

Tags: python, class, oop

There is a Python class, say `Environment`, which will need to call methods from other classes, say `Pedestrian`, `Car`, `Plane`. In practice, I pass in an instance of these classes into some method of `Environment`, and this method calls a method of the object that is passed in. `Pedestrian`, `Car`, `Plane` share some method for similar functionality, say `get_speed`, but `get_speed` should be called with different inputs depending on the object: for example `Pedestrian.get_speed(soil_type)` and `Plane.get_speed(weather_type, air_resistance)`. Some method in `Environment` calls `.get_speed` of the object that is passed in at some point. My issue is that I want this call from `Environment` to work for any object that is passed in, so I need to handle different input sets to `object_passed_in.get_speed` depending on the type of `object_passed_in`. What is an efficient / elegant way of doing this?

What I was thinking to do:

1. Add to the `get_speed` method, for all these objects, the arguments `*args`, `**kwargs`, and just ignore whatever arguments get captured by these
2. In the `Environment` class, call `object_passed_in.get_speed` with all the possibly useful parameters (`soil_type`, `air_resistance`,  weather_type`, etc.), and discard whatever arguments are captured in *args, **kwargs.

Is this solution fine? (It does not seem very clean to me) Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Environment` should not care about the details. Instead, the caller of the `Envioronment` method should be responsible for passing the necessary arguments.

```
class Environment:

    # Precondition: argument obj must have a callable 'get_speed' attribute
    def foo(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        speed = obj.get_speed(*args, **kwargs)
        ...


...

e = Evironment()
e.foo(ped, soil_type="dirt")
e.foo(plane, "cloudy", .032)
# etc
```

Possibly better, `Environment.foo` should not even need to know that `get_speed` is being called; instead, it can take a zero-argument function to call, and the function passed takes care of calling the object's `get_speed` method with the correct arguments. This can be simpler if `foo` itself needs to take arguments other than those to be passed to `get_speed`.

```
from functools import partial


class Environment:

    def foo(self, f, x):
        speed = f()


e = Environment()
e.foo(partial(ped.get_speed, soil_type="dirt"), 9)
e.foo(partial(plane.get_speed, "cloudy", .032), 6)
# etc
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Can you please explain to me why capturing all arguments into *args, **kwargs (and, I assume, just retrieving whatever arguments from *args **kwargs are useful within the methods in `Pedestrian`, `Plane`), is better than explicitly naming all arguments into `obj.get_speed`, called from `Environment.foo`? I get a feel for it, but I cannot quite explain why. Secondly, why would your second solution be simpler if `foo` itself needs to take arguments other than those to be passed to `get_speed` (it is indeed the case)?

Comment: It's a matter of encapsulation. `Environment` doesn't necessarily need to know the names of the arguments expected by `get_speed` in order to pass them on. There may even be subclasses of `Plane`, `Car`, etc that don't exist when you write `Environment`, so you *can't* know what arguments they might take.

Comment: If `foo` takes a fixed set of positional arguments, it's not too big a deal: `foo`'s arguments come first, anything left over is passed on to `get_speed`. But that precludes `foo` itself from taking an arbitrary number of arguments: there's no way to tell where `foo's` arguments stop and `get_speed`'s arguments start.